# Cannot detect user leaving channel discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have connected two discord bot accounts to one script and i want to kick a user when they leave a voice channel but it doesn't work.
code:

```
const { Client, Intents, ClientUser } = require('discord.js');
const cli = require('nodemon/lib/cli');

const clients = [ new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] }), new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] }) ];

const Tokens = ["token1", "token2"]

clients.forEach(function(client, index) {
    client.login(Tokens[index])
    let clientcount = index + 1
    client.on("ready", () => {
        client.user.setUsername("PartyChat Bot")
        client.user.setActivity(`PartyChat Bot #${clientcount}`)
        console.log(`PartyBot #${clientcount} is online`)
    })
});

clients.forEach(function(client, index) {
    client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
        let newUserChannel = newState.voiceChannel
        let oldUserChannel = oldState.voiceChannel
      
      
        if(oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
      
           // User Joins a voice channel
      
        } else if(newUserChannel === null){
            console.log("user left")
            newState.member.kick()      
        }
      })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
if(oldState.channel && !newState.channel){
// code block
}
```

this detects if user was in channel and left without joining new channel.

Comment: sorry it still doesnt work i have no idea why.